# What is the impact of ignoring OpenGL typedefs?

Tags: opengl, typedef

So, I am using OpenGL which typedefs `unsigned integer` -> `GLuint`.

For some reason it feels wrong to sprinkle my program with GLuint, instead of the more generic unsigned integer or uint32_t.

Any thoughts on negative/positive aspects of ignoring the typedefs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typedefs are there to make your code more portable.  If you ever wanted to move to a platform in which a `GLuint` may have a different underlying type (For whatever reason), it would be wise to use the `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the chance that your code gets ported to a platform where `GLuint != unsigned int`. If you are going to ignore the typedefs, then at least add some compile time checks that result in a compilation error if they are different than what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

In general, see the above answers by K-ballo and Chad La Guardia, that's the intent behind such typedefs. That, and in some cases to hide the actual datatype in case the API changes in a future revision (not likely going to happen with OpenGL, but I've seen it happen). In case the datatype changes, this requires a recompilation, but no code changes.
Still, one has to say that library developers often overdo this particular aspect of portabilty to the point of sillyness.

In this particular case, the OpenGL specification is very clear about what a `GLuint` is (chapter 2.4). It is an unsigned integer of at least 32 bits length. They don't leave much room for interpretation or change.

Insofar, there is no chance it could *ever* be anything other than an `uint32_t` (as that is the very definition of `uint32_t`), and there is no good reason why you couldn't use `uint32_t` in its stead if you prefer to do so (other than using GLuint makes explicit that a variable is meant to be used with OpenGL, but meh).
It might in principle *still* be something different than an `unsigned int` of course, since not much is said about the precise size of an `int` (other than `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short)`).